# react-app-rewired build with Module parse failed: Unexpected token You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use `react-app-rewired build` to build React application using tsx

But I got the error when building reactapp

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (256:123)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
* ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|  *     not null.
|  */
> var gen_bitlen = function gen_bitlen(s, desc) /*    deflate_state *s;*/ /*    tree_desc *desc;    /* the tree descriptor */*/{
|   var tree = desc.dyn_tree;
|   var max_code = desc.max_code;
```

my env

```
 % node -v
v14.19.1
 % npm -v
8.19.3
 % yarn -v
1.22.19
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src", "internals/startingTemplate/**/*"],
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noEmit": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "types": [
        "node"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone gets the same problems with me. I don't update any package.
I check and see that @babel lib version changed to v7.20.2 (21 hours ago)
may be some package that I use depeding on babel
But I am not sure

Comment: follow this thread : https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15132

Answer (score 0):

Because of updating from Babel: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15132

so just add to package.json file, remove all cache, node module, and rebuild

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/core": "7.19.0"
  }
```